# How to determine minimum word length of regular language

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Given a regular language $L$ and a regular expression $r$ with $L=L(r)$. Is it possible to determine the minimum length of words of $L(r)$ by the structure of $r$?

A straightforward example:

Let's say we have a regular expression $r=aac^*aa$, then $L(R) = \{aaaa, aacaa, aaccaa, \dots, aac^naa\}$. To determine the minimal length I would erase everything that is postfixed with $*$, leaving $r'=aaaa$. Now I would count the concatenations and add 1, which would yield in this example, not unsurprisingly, a minimum length of 4.

Is there a general approach to do this for more complex expressions?

**Sidenote:** I need to achieve this without the help of automata.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, notice that you can easily eliminate $\emptyset$ for all regular expressions other than a regular expression describing the empty language. To do this, you use the following rewriting rules, which define an operator $E$ on regular expressions:

- $E[\sigma] = \sigma$, $E[\epsilon] = \epsilon$, $E[\emptyset] = \emptyset$.
- $E[r_1 r_2]$ is $\emptyset$ if one of $E[r_1],E[r_2]$ is $\emptyset$, and $E[r_1]E[r_2]$ otherwise.
- $E[r_1 + r_2]$ is $E[r_1]$ if $E[r_2] = \emptyset$, $E[r_2]$ if $E[r_1] = \emptyset$, and $E[r_1] + E[r_2]$ otherwise.
- $E[r^*] = \epsilon$ if $E[r] = \emptyset$, and $E[r]^*$ otherwise.

You can prove inductively that $E[r]$ either doesn't contain $\emptyset$, or is equal to $\emptyset$.

Applying these rewriting rules, we have either determined that the denotation of the regular expression is empty, or are given a regular expression without $\emptyset$. Now we define an operator $m$ which determines the length of the minimal word in an $\emptyset$-free regular expression:

- $m(\sigma) = 1$, $m(\epsilon) = 0$.
- $m(r_1r_2) = m(r_1) + m(r_2)$.
- $m(r_1 + r_2) = \min(m(r_1),m(r_2))$.
- $m(r^*) = 0$.

---

You can also implement both operators at once, by allowing $m$ to output $\infty$ (meaning that the language defined by the regular expression is empty):

- $m(\sigma) = 1$, $m(\epsilon) = 0$, $m(\emptyset) = \infty$.
- $m(r_1r_2) = m(r_1)+m(r_2)$, where $\infty + \ell = \ell + \infty = \infty$.
- $m(r_1+r_2) = \min(m(r_1),m(r_2))$, where $\min(\infty,\ell) = \min(\ell,\infty) = \ell$.
- $m(r^*) = 0$.

Comment: The way you handle the problem with the empty set (in the last of these equations) ls great. It seems to be an application of the [tropical semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_semiring).

Comment: This looks promising! Thank you!

Comment: What is $m(r_1 \times r_2)$ (the product DFA)?

Comment: The function $m$ gets as input a regular expression, not a DFA. Moreover, semantically it gets as input a language (given as a regular expression) rather than a machine. It is a function about languages rather than about machines that decide them.

Answer (score 6):

The general idea from the previous answer is right but unnecessarily inefficient. 
Compute a NFA recognizing the regular expression. Find with BFS the shortest path from the start state to some endstate. 
The corresponding word is the shortest accepted word.

Comment: I don't think this works, since $\epsilon$-transitions contribute to the path's length but not to the word's length. You can use a weighted graph instead. If properly implemented, the complexity will be unchanged since all the weights will be in $\{0,1\}$ and all the distances in $\{0, \dots, n-1\}$, where $n$ is the number of states.

Comment: Usually NFAs (as I know them) are defined without epsilon transitions. But when considering them, you're right. However there is a method to replace those

Comment: Yup, there is an algorithm that from a regular expression directly constructs an NFA without $\varepsilon$-transitions: [Glushkov's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov%27s_construction_algorithm), as opposed to the more common approach by Thompson that uses a lot of these transitions.  (But the answer by Yuval works on expressions and avoids any explicit automata.)

Comment: This is a handy approach, especially using a Glushkov Automaton, but unfortunately I need to do it without an automaton. Sorry, I didn't made that clear in my question!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a general approach to do this for more complex expressions?

Yes, there is a way. Note that a regular language is the language accepted by a *NFA/DFA* so the general approach to problems of this kind is to convert your expression into its corresponding *NFA/DFA* and then lexicographically search through all the words of the language until you find the first one that is accepted by your machine (reach the final state). I am not aware of other general methods besides this one.

Comment: Once you have the NFA/DFA you don't need to lexicographically search thorough all the words. It suffices to compute any shortest path from the starting state to any final state. If you have a DFA then you can just do a BFS visit. If you have a NFA then you can assign weight $0$ to $\epsilon$-transitions and weight $1$ to the other transitions. Then you can use Dijkstra's algorithm.