# What is the minimum length word accepted by the product of these simple loop automata?

Tags: algorithms, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Let $A_{n} = (aa|aaa|aaaa|\dots |a^{n-2})(a^{n})^* $ where $n \geq 4$ is some natural,and  $A_2 = (a^2)^*, A_3 = (a^3)^*$.  Clearly every transition is thus labeled by an $a$.  From now on let $A_n$ denote the DFA that accepts the given $n$th regex.

Clearly we can model $A_n$ with a DFA that is one big loop with every state being accepted *except* for the second and "second from last" state.

Let $N \subset\Bbb{N}$ be a finite set.  Consider the product DFA: $A = \prod_{n \in N} A_n$.

Given that I made these DFA's incredibly simple - they're just one big loop - is it feasible that there exists a formula for a really tight estimate the length of the minimum word accepted by $A$?

Has anyone researched this ? I googled but all I could find was minimum word length in a PDA.

Comment: Found this upon second googling: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/117096/12373

This is very nice!  But what happens under products?